# NSString addition what does this Objective-c code do?

Tags: objective-c, categories

Ran across this NSString Addition and I hav no idea what it does or is used for?

```
NSString *NSStringWithFormat(NSString *formatString, ...) {
va_list args;
va_start(args, formatString);

NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString arguments:args];

va_end(args);

#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(objc_arc)
    return string;
#else 
    return [string autorelease];
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a C function that lets you do this:

```
NSString *str = NSStringWithFormat(@"This is a number: %d", someIntValue);
```

instead of this:

```
// No ARC
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a number: %d", someIntValue];
```

or

```
// With ARC
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is a number: %d", someIntValue];
```

Seems kind of pointless to me since with or without ARC you can use the "No ARC" code. This C function only saves a few characters.